# Is there a fundamental limit to the precision of calculations?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, data-analysis

For daily applications, it is accepted that there are limitations to the precision of our calculations when we want to compute quantities that are  rational multiples of irrational numbers.

Then Feynman gave us the idea of using quantum systems to perform quantum computations; the meaning is the system is the computation.

Extrapolating this to every calculation the universe performs out there, for example: calculating the time it takes for a photon to reach the earth from the sun, is there a limit to how accurately this can be calculated by the universe? If yes, what are the implications?

Comment: Calculated by the universe?? Do you mean precision of measurements rather than precision of calculations?

Comment: Any mention of the universe doing calculations is purely metaphorical. Not to be taken literally!

Comment: @Qmechanic no, I was of the opinion that the universe performs all these calculations for all physical processes in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically the reals numbers have infinite “precision”.

Computationally any real number can be approximated with arbitrarily high precision given sufficient computational memory.

Physically any physical parameter is measured to non-zero finite uncertainty which, in a sense, limits a precision. That said this precision limit is not fundamental. Better technology may decrease the uncertainty of measurements allowing for higher “precision”.

Answer (score 0):

At what point has the Earth been reached? Ozone layer (for UV photons)?, summit of Everest?, or Mount Chimborazo?, or mean sea level?

That's 25 miles of uncertainty.

Where is the surface of the Sun? The photosphere is 250 miles thick.

What's the date? The distance to the sun varies by 3,000,000 miles...that's 16 seconds of ????

So your example can't even be defined to a level that challenges our ability to measure time.